# Getting SQLException: Driver:org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver returned null for URL in tomee

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tomcat7, apache-tomee

I am getting following exception in tomee deployed application.

```
 [EL Severe]: 2014-07-11 09:18:34.811--ServerSession(860687693)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8081-exec-3,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver@7078c2bb returned null for URL:"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB"
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManagerRegistry.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManagerRegistry.java:115)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.find(JtaEntityManager.java:164)
```

heres my **tomee.xml** file,

```
<tomee>
  <Resource id="testDBPool" type="DataSource">
    jdbcDriverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB"
    username = "admin"
    password = "admin"
  </Resource>
</tomee>
```

I already put **mysql_connector** jar in my **tomee/lib** folder.
My **persistence.xml** file as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TestPersistence"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/testDBPool</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINEST" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I do not understand where I am wrong, why I am getting this exception?
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: why are you adding the Microsoft SQL Server driver (`sqljdbc4`)  if you are using MySQL?

Comment: I have removed the sqljdbc4.jar, but facing the same problem.

Comment: Looks like a bug in EclipseLink, the `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver` doesn't support a mysql JDBC url and so it should return null as specified in the javadoc of [`java.sql.Driver.connect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#connect-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-) : _"The driver should return "null" if it realizes it is the wrong kind of driver to connect to the given URL."_ That, or you have a configuration error and are pointing to a datasource that is actually configured to use hsqldb, but with a MySQL url.

Comment: driver class specified is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` but the exception is `Getting SQLException: Driver:org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver returned null` how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong property name to declare the JDBC driver. According to [Apache TomEE: DataSource Configuration](https://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html), the property for the driver name is **`jdbcDriver`**, and not `jdbcDriverClassName`. The default value for `jdbcDriver` is `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver`. So as I commented earlier it will try to create a connection using HSQLDB, but with a MySQL JDBC url.

To fix your problem change your configuration to:

```
<tomee>
  <Resource id="testDBPool" type="DataSource">
    jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    ...
  </Resource>
</tomee>
```

Comment: That one is solved, but now I am facing another exception. I have two connection pools 'xyz' and 'abc'. When I tried to run application then it is throwing abc.tableName not exist, whereas actually the tableName is exist in xyz schema not in abc, but why it is pointing to wrong schema?

Comment: @milind Ask a new question, and I suggest you provide more details