# Getting SQLException: Driver:org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver returned null for URL in tomee when Resource is defined with system properties

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-tomee

I try to define a DataSource resource through system properties (in contrast to putting it into tomee.xml) and get the very same result as in [Getting SQLException: Driver:org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver returned null for URL in tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691524/getting-sqlexception-driverorg-hsqldb-jdbcdriver-returned-null-for-url-in-tome/24711243#24711243).

What's different is, that I provide a value for the property jdbcDriver and that I define my DataSource through system properties:

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS='new://Resource?type=javax.sql.DataSource'"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS.jdbcDriver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS.jdbcUrl='jdbc:mysql://ahost/adb'"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS.userName='auser'"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS.password='apass'"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS.maxActive=5"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS.maxIdle=5"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS.minIdle=1"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DmyDS.initialSize=1"
```

Since the stacktrace also contains the value of jdbcUrl I am pretty sure the values are processed by TomEE properly, just the wrong driver (HSQL) seems to be selected

The mysql-connector JAR is in $TOMEE_BASE/lib. Putting the datasource definition into tomee.xml works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the reason was a class loader conflict. The MySQL connector was both in the WAR (by accident) and in TomEE. After removing the driver from the WAR things start to work.

Still very strange that it falls back to HSQLDB without further notice about some driver issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your shell but I'd remove the simple quotes. Also even if less important tomee tends to prefer to use attributes starting with an uppercase even if not case sensitive for most of them.